# Variables in AngularJS directives with isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directive with an isolated scope.

My scope looks like this:

```
scope: {
    amount: "=itemsPerPage",
}
```

My directive:

```
<list items-per-page="5"></list>
```

In my directive link function I have:

```
scope.test = scope.amount;
console.log(scope.test);
console.log(scope.amount);
```

But the output in console is:

```
undefined
5
```

I don't understand why? How does it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this actual code or is it retyped? I can see you have `scope.test = scope.amout` but then you console log `scope.amount`. Looks like an "n" is missing

Comment: sorry, it was retyped. there must be amount

Comment: @TurakVladyslav: I suspect value of amount is still not ready to set value in scope.text because it still in asynchronous process. You can add setTimeout to validate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st one doesn't work because variable name is not correct

convert this

```
scope.test = scope.amout;
```

to

```
scope.test = scope.amount;
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2L0ursu6/)

Comment: sorry, it was retyped. there must be amount

Comment: @TurakVladyslav after changing name it works fine for me. i have added my fiddle in my answer

Comment: sorry, there was "amout", i really must go sleep :D